# Parsing deleted pdfs

Tags: c++, pdf, computer-forensics

I'm trying to do some file carving on a disk with c++. I can't find any resources on the web related to the on-disk structure of a pdf file. The thing is that I can find the %PDF-1.x token at the start of a cluster but I can't find out the size of a PDF file anywhere.

Let's say hypothetically that the file system entry for this particular document is lost. I find the start of the document and I keep reading until I run into the "startxref *number* %%EOF". The thing is that I don't know when to stop since there are multiple "%%EOF" markers in the content of a document.

I've tried stopping after reading, let's say 10 clusters, and not finding any pdf specific keyword like "obj", "stream", "trailer", "xref" anywhere. But it's quite arbitrary and it's not a deterministic method of finding the ending of the document so I can determine it's size.

I've also seen some "Length *number*" markers at the start of some "obj"s but the number doesn't really fit most of the time.

Any ideas on what I can try next? Is there a way to determine the exact size of the entire document? I'm interested in recovering documents programmatically.

Comment: Have you looked at the pdf reference? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

Comment: Yes, I've looked for some clues but I haven't entirely read it. I'm doing so now but I'm not so sure it will help. Also, I'm interested in all pdf versions, not just 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PDF's are "free format" (pretty much like text files, but with less obviousness to humans when it comes to "reading" the content), it's probably hard to piece them together if they aren't in order.

A `stream` does have a length, which is a key to where the `endstream` goes. (A blank line before and after the stream itself). Streams are used t introduce bitmaps and similar things [fonts, line-art data in compressed form, etc] into the document). But if you have several 4KB segments that could go in as the same block in the middle of a stream then there's no way to tell which way they go, other than pasting it together and seeing which ones look sane and which doesn't. Similarly, if there are several segments of streams and objects, you can't really tell which goes where.

Of course, this applies to almost all types of files with "variable content" - you can find the first few kilobytes of a JPG, but knowing what the REST of the of is, won't be easy - only be visually inspecting the content can you determine which blocks of bytes belong where - if you get it wrong, you'll probably just get some random garbage.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to match streams as best as I can if the stream length fits with the endstream. I would guess that streams are close together, right?

Comment: You can guess that, but it all depends on the fragmentation of the disk - and note that the number of streams in a PDF can be any number from 1 to infinity. The whole document may be one or a few large bitmap images, for example!

Comment: About that, are resources like bitmaps fully pasted into the content of the document? What I mean is, a bitmap image has a field that has an approximate file size. Maybe I can use that as an extra validation for streams. So far I've looked at maybe 20 pdfs version 1.3 through 1.5 and they seem to have 2 startxref and %%EOF pairs. One at the start and one at the end. I can maybe use the last one as a definite end.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to "assemble the original PDF"? If so, you need all the stream content in order. streams are just "content", it's not required to be in any particular format - it can be compressed text, bitmaps (JPG, BMP, TIFF, etc) or any number of other formats.

Comment: I'm trying to find out the size of the pdf file for recovery assuming the file is not fragmented at all.

Comment: There should definitely be a %%EOF at the end of it, but there can be several.

Comment: *they seem to have 2 startxref and %%EOF pairs. One at the start and one at the end.* — that sounds like a special case, a linearized one. In general there can be way more %%EOF markers.

Comment: I finally found a few pdfs that have more of those markers. It took me a while to find some. I'll see what I can come up with to carve them. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1):

The open source tool [`bulk_extractor`](http://github.com/simsong/bulk_extractor/) has a module called `scan_pdf` that does pretty much what you are describing here. It can recognize the individual parts of a PDF file on a drive, automatically decompresses the compressed regions, and extracts text using a two strategies. It will recover data from fragments of PDFs even if the `xref` table cannot be found.